# How to read BC4 texture in GLSL?

Tags: textures, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm supposed to receive a texture in BC4 format.
In OpenGL, i guess this format is called GL_COMPRESSED_RED_RGTC1.

The texture is not really a "texture", more like a data to handle at fragment shader.

Usually, to get colors from a texture within a fragment shader, i do :

```
uniform sampler2D TextureUnit;
void main()
{
   vec4 TexColor = texture2D(TextureUnit, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0]));
(...)
```

the result of which is obviously a v4, for RGBA.

But now, i'm supposed to receive a single float from the read.
I'm struggling to understand how this is achieved.

Should i still use a texture sampler, and expect the value to be in a specific position (for example, within TexColor.r ?), or should i use something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of having one-channel images you should use `texture2D` as follows

`float TexColor = texture2D(TextureUnit, gl_TexCoord[0]).r`

which basically forces to read only the first (and only) channel of the image and stores its value into TexColor. At least, this is how I handle shadow maps for example (which are stored in one-channel images.

Comment: "*which basically forces to read only the first (and only) channel of the image and stores its value into TexColor.*" Um, no. It reads all four; it *ignores* the other three.

Answer (score 5):

Let's provide a complete answer.

First:

```
texture2D(TextureUnit, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0]))
```

Since we're talking about RGTC, we're in GL 3.x+ land. You shouldn't be using `texture2D` anymore; just use `texture`. That way, if you change the type of `TextureUnit`, everything will still work. But that's minor.

Also, `vec(gl_TexCoord[0])` is better spelled `gl_TexCoord[0].xy`. But again, minor.

The main thing is this: accessing a (non-shadow) texture *always* returns a 4-component vector. It doesn't matter what the texture's format is; it returns 4 components. If a texture doesn't actually provide all of the components, then the missing components will be filled in by the vector (0, 0, 0, 1).

Let's take your format: `GL_COMPRESSED_RED_RGTC1`. This uses the `RGTC1` style of compression, and it provides the `RED` color component. So it fills in only the red component; every texture access will therefore be (R, 0, 0, 1). If your format was `GL_COMPRESSED_RG_RGTC1`, then you would get the `R` and `G` components; every texture access would provide (R, G, 0, 1).

Therefore, if you want the red component from the texture, just ask for it:

```
texture(TextureUnit, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).r
```

Of course, [texture swizzling](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask) can mess around with this too. But that's a discussion for another time.

Answer (score 4):

From the shader's perspective, a block-compressed texture like BC4/RGTC1 behaves just like any other texture; the GPU hardware automatically handles the block decompression and filtering on your behalf. BC4 is a single-channel texture, so you are correct: use texture2D() -- or texture() in more recent GL versions -- and the data you want will be in the TexColor.r field.

Comment: Great answer, thanks ! Another question which is almost the same : later on, i will have to handle BC5 textures (basically, two BC4 textures together). I guess i'll have to fetch the results from R & G fields ?

Comment: Yup, that's all that would need to change in the shader.